# Debian wheezy offline UPGRADE

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy

I using Debian(Wheezy) with 3.2.0-4 amd64 kernel version,I was installed both of "usb-modeswitch" and "usb-modeswitch-data" packages but Debian don't detect my 3g-modem-usb dongle.

Now i think i should upgrade my kernel to newest version like(3.13.3 stable),But i have not internet connection through my Debian OS,I was download "3.13.3 tar.xz" Kernel Source form Kernel.org ,Can any body explain for me how can i compile and upgrade kernel from 3.2 to 3.13.3 without internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While building and using a vanilla kernel from kernel.org is possible, it is usually not needed.

Try a backport from backports.debian.org first : there are binary packages that you can download using another OS/PC/whatever, for instance on a USB stick, and install directly as root or with sudo using

```
dpkg -i <file.deb list>
```

To upgrade kernel, you need to download linux-image, and linux-headers can be useful if you need to install third-party driver. You'll need dependancies as well. The last available version on backports.debian.org is currently 3.12, so for your amd64 installation, search linux-image-3.12 and linux-headers-3.12 on https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/ and get the dependancies as well.

It would probably be better to install everything via a public wifi or something, adding wheezy-backports source to your sources.lists.

If you really want to upgrade your kernel with vanilla kernel from kernel.org, look into make-kpkg, this native debian tool is designed to help you generate proper debian packages from kernel source.

Note that if you have an USB 3G modem and want to make it work on Linux, you should first check what chipset it is using, and what is needed to make it work with linux, if possible at all : upgrading kernel may not be sufficient or even necessary.

Comment: ,Thank you for your good information,I migrate from OpenSuse to Debian ; On OpenSuse after upgrading kernel every things goes to worked perfectly.I hope this will fix my problem!